# How to align all td to center except a td with class

Tags: php, html, css

For example i have these codes

```
<tr>
 <td class="foo">chuchu</td>
 <td>chuchu</td>
 <td>chuchu</td>
 <td>chuchu</td>
 <td>chuchu</td>
</tr>
```

how can i align them to center except the td with class?

Comment: is `class="foo"` the only exception?

Comment: @Miggy yess,  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this—

`tr:not(:first-child) { text-align: center; }`

The combination of the `:not` and the `:first-child` selectors will make sure the styling skips the first child of a parent div.

But if your order of items aren't known, then try—

`:not([class])`

So, in your case, `td:not(.foo) { text-align: center; }` should work.

Comment: @john-bryan-callega Edited the CSS typo. Try it now.

Comment: Great! this works, I'm trying to do it with jQuery but this seems fine.

Comment: Awesome. :) Yeah, jQuery is overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this. Based on your answer to my question in the comment section, I came up with a simpler solution:

**.css**

```
td{
    text-align:center;
}

.foo{
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: This a better answer and compatibility shouldn't be a problem as well.

Comment: @Miggy I agree. Definitely simpler and more compatible, yes, but IMHO, I don't think we should write specific over-ride classes, for the sake of maintainability. What's your take?

Comment: @SujanSundareswaran as for me, I just want to help by posting another answer. But hey, as long as it works its fine with me, im just a carefree developer and still learning things :)

Comment: Personally, I prefer leveraging [CSS' specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Both answers were fine and worked properly, but i don't know what's better in overriding or not in classes, i think i should do research about it. Cheers :)